# Open VPN Client

Tags: windows

I have created an OpenVPN server at my house, and while that seems to be working, I am having trouble with the client. Whenever I try to start the client, I get this error.

Comment: Please don't remove questions *especially* after someone answered them.

Comment: Why did you remove the links to the errors? Are they no longer relevant somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, line 42 of the config file is incorrect. It should read `remote 192.168.1.132 1194` instead of just `192.168.1.132 1194`.